# how to use $timeout in ng-click markup

Tags: angularjs

I want to wait some time after click, then processed.

i tried:

```
<button ng-click="$timeout(save,500);">Save<button>
```

controller

```
$scope.save = function() {
      // save.
}
```

no error in console.

what i doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As 'Paolo Moretti' said, the way to use $timeout **in ng-click markup** is attach the $timeout service to $scope.

### HTML

```
<button ng-click="$timeout(save,500);">Save<button>
```

### Javascript

```
$scope.$timeout = $timeout; // must be injected in controller.
$scope.save = function() {
      // save.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Move the code to your controller:

```
<button ng-click="clickHandler()">DO-IT<button>

$scope.clickHandler = function() {
   $timeout($scope.save, 500);
}

$scope.save = function() {
   // save
}
```

Comment: no way, i need it on markup. the save function is already used in other poins.

Comment: @rnrneverdies You can either declare a new function `saveWithTimeout` or attach `$timeout` to the `$scope`.

Comment: I think it's better answer. Keeping the "logic" inside controller make the code cleaner and easier to use.